# Why a downloaded app can read/write to ~/Downloads/ without requiring the privacy allow permission in Big Sur?

Tags: applications, permission, big-sur, privacy

In MacOS Big Sur, I figured out an app (downloaded from internet) normally can not access `~/Downloads/`, `~/Documents/`, `~/Desktop/` folders directly. When it tries to access those folders at the first time, there will be a popup window to ask for permission and the permission can be setup in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Files and Folders**.

**Edited:** It seems my bad description makes people confused (sorry about my English). I will put two screenshots here to clarify what I mean:

[image]

The above screenshot appears when the app `iTerm2` tries to access `~/Downloads` folder at the first time in Big Sur. (basically when I execute `ls ~/Downloads/` commands in iTerm2)

[image]

The above screenshot is where I can change the folders privacy setup.

But, today, I downloaded an app (it's a downloading tool) and installed it by dragging it to `/Applications` folder. (the same way I installed `iTerm2`) I tried to use that tool to download a file to `~/Downloads` folder and the file can be downloaded and written to `~/Downloads` folder directly without any permission requirement. It can also display/read all the files in the `~/Downloads` folder. I checked the Privacy setup in System Preferences and it does NOT have that app setup too.

I am very confused how can that app read/write the file to ~/Downloads without requiring a privacy permission on the protected folder. I thought those protected folders were protected and were not allowed to be read/write before granting privacy permission. But I was wrong.
(Note that, later I found out **Google Chrome App** can read/write those protected folders too without asking this privacy permission. *File* > *Open File* > Choose any files inside the three protected folders)

**PS1:** I haven't mentioned the "downloading tool app" name here because that is a non-English app. If anyone consider I should give the name to get a better help, just let me know. Thanks.

**PS2:** This is a fresh install of MacOS Big Sur. (Not a upgraded system)

**PS3:** The "downloading tool app" is a GUI app. (NOT a CML app).

**PS4:** I just find out the `Google Chrome.app` downloaded from https://chrome.google.com can write to (save file to) `~/Downloads/` folder directly without requiring any privacy permission too. This is weird. Why does `iTerm`, `Code` and `VLC` require privacy permission to do any read/write to those protected folders but google chrome does NOT need to require anything.

Comment: What permissions are set on the Downloads folder?

Comment: @SolarMike The question is about MacOS new feature Security & Priavcy > Privacy > FIles and Folders. I think that has nothing to do with the file system folder permission. This is a fresh install of Big Sur. So the Downloads folder should have the default permission. Since you ask, that is `drwx------+ 9 myusername  staff` here. Cheers.

Comment: I would be much less concerned about write access than read access to ~/Downloads. If there's always an OS-provided picker, or files go directly to ~/Downloads, that's a different issue than arbitrary apps being able to _read_ files in the ~/Downloads folder.

Comment: @pseudon yeah, you are right. I am more concerned about read access too. They actually have read access too, but I haven't put it in the question. I tried Google Chrome, it can read/open any files inside those protected folders without any privacy requirement.

Comment: Did you grant full disk access to the absent question? It's right above the files and folders section of the security preferences in your screenshot. Did those apps ask for permission for full disc access when you installed them?

Comment: @hepcat72 no, I didn't do that. You can see my screenshot in the question. If I grant any app full disk access, you can see it in the **Files and Folders** option too. If you use chrome, you can simply prove this behavior by clicking **File** > **Open File** > Choose files in protected folder and open it in the Google Chrome app.

Comment: I see that in Catalina, but I wasn't sure about Big Sur. Your screen shot shows none with full disk access. If they work the same, then you're right.

Comment: I don't know what the specific app is, but I assume what you're seeing is a system control (such as an open/save dialog), not the **application** enumerating the files.  Finder always has rights on ~/Downloads.

Comment: The security feature you're talking about is called Transparency, Consent and Control (TCC), but the name isn't that widely known (so it isn't a great search term).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question. [Asking why Apple does things is explicitly off topic.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) If you are solving a specific problem given how Apple has chosen / engineered / delivered their operating system, please make a substantial edit to focus on the practical problem and not just Why is this...